How to check for updates in my C# app published on MS Store
I am a Mac developer who has just started building Windows apps. My app will be published to the Windows Store.
Do apps downloaded from the Windows Store have to check for new versions themselves, or does the Windows Store do it automatically in a similar way to the Mac AppStore?
I have read a lot of posts about checking for app updates (most of them are over 10 yo) and I would like to know if there is a standard way to do this. I know about ClickOnce, but I think it requires the Visual Studio Publish method to use it? And I would prefer to use other installers (e.g. Installer Project extension or Inno Setup).

When you publish your app to the Windows Store, the store handles updates automatically, similar to the Mac App Store. Users will receive updates through the Microsoft Store without needing to check for new versions themselves. This ensures that your app remains up-to-date with minimal effort on your part.
Regarding ClickOnce, you’re correct that it typically requires the Visual Studio Publish method. However, since you prefer using other installers like the Installer Project extension or Inno Setup, you can still manage updates manually if needed. But for apps distributed through the Windows Store, relying on the store’s automatic update mechanism is usually the best approach.

Thanks! Do I need to add any code to my app to receive updates, or is this solely the responsibility of the Windows Store and happens completely outside of the app?
